# mailgun not sending email returning undefined data

Tags: node.js, angular, http, mailgun

I am trying to implement a simple email confirmation on signup flow using Angular 4, nodejs, mailgun-js and mailgun. The problem is the mailgun send:

```
mailgun.messages().send(data, function(error, body) {
        console.log(body);
    });
```

is timing out with the following error on the front-end:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/users/sendMail net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
core.js:1448 ERROR 
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: null, ok: false, …}
error
:
ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: "error", …}
headers
:
HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}
message
:
"Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error"
name
:
"HttpErrorResponse"
ok
:
false
status
:
0
statusText
:
"Unknown Error"
url
:
null
__proto__
:
HttpResponseBase
```

The back-end show now errors but the return value (body) is undefined and the email is not sent. This is my complete back-end sendMail module:

```
const api_key = '<key-f40360259dea7c667ca06d4aee956421>';
const DOMAIN = '<sandbox836cdf3cfe9c467b916fe5bb0d73e7e7.mailgun.org>';
const mailgun = require('mailgun-js')({ apiKey: api_key, domain: DOMAIN });
// ---------------- sendMail variables -----

router.post('/sendMail', (req, res, next) => {

    console.log("Email message data: " + JSON.stringify(req.body));

    const data = {
        from: 'xxxxdev@gmail.com',
        to: [req.body.email, 'xxxxxxx@gmail.com'],
        name: req.body.firstName,
        code: req.body.workshopCode,
        subject: req.body.workshopTitle,
        text: req.body.messageBody
    };

    mailgun.messages().send(data, function(error, body) {
        console.log(body);
    });
});
```

Both From and To email are valid email address and the req.body displayed in the console.log is the correct data passed from the Front-End.

This the Front-end sendmail module:

```
 sendEmailConfirmation(message) {
     const headers = new HttpHeaders();
     headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

     this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/users/sendMail', message).subscribe((data) => {
          console.log('Mail return data: ' + data);   >>>THIS LINE IS NEVER EXECUTED<<<<<<
              },
        );
  }
```

What am I missing here??.....

I noticed the absence of a res.send so I added the following:

```
if (error) throw error;
        else {
            res.send('Email sent');
        }
```

Now I get a forbidden error on the back-end:

```
(node:10780) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Forbidden
    at IncomingMessage.res.on (C:\connect2Server\node_modules\mailgun-js\lib\request.js:301:17)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:165:20)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1101:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:152:19)
(node:10780) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a ca
tch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
```

Comment: Have you tried logging the error in the callback to the mailgun API call? The reason you're getting `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` is because you never end the request after you've sent the mail, with something like `res.sendStatus(200)` for success or `res.sendStatus(500)` for an error.

Comment: @Svenskunganka I did notice that and end it with(see the edit) res.send('......'). I got  the following:...(node:10780) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Forbidden

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that if you are sending from Europe to also include the `host` like this:

```
const mg = mailgun({apiKey: MAILGUN_PRIVATE_API_KEY, domain: MAILGUN_DOMAIN_NAME, host:MAILGUN_HOST});
```

For Europe, `host` is `api.eu.mailgun.net` and for America it's `api.mailgun.net` from what I know.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.....caused by typo in mailgun credentials. The '<' '>' brackets where copied over .....the clue was the Forbidden error.